# Issue populating some fields dynamically using Javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, api, dynamicform

Am working on a form whereby I populate the fields on the form dynamically from an API. The fields are being **populated well in Google chrome and works well but fails in Firefox**.. Seems the JS code am using to populate the fields is not working in Firefox

~ Please assist

**Form Layout**

```
<form 
   id="eazzycheckout-payment-form"
   action="https://api-test.*****************" method="POST">

   <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="">
   <input type="hidden" id="orderReference" name="orderReference" value="">
   <input type="hidden" id="orderID" name="orderID" value="">

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title payment"><a href="#" id="mpesa" class="mpesa">Make Payment</a></h5>
    </div>

  <!--END-->
  </form>
```

**AJAX code containing Response from the API whereby I populate the response to the form fields dynamically**

```
//Fetch input fields via their id
    var amount = $('#amount');
    var orderID = $('#orderID');
    var  orderRef = $('#orderReference');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jengaAPI',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            //console.log(response);
            //Fetch from response
            //Amount
            amount.val(response.amount);
            orderID.val(response.payment_reference);
            orderRef.val(response.payment_reference);

            //console.log(amount.val());
            //console.log(orderRef.val());

            $('#eazzycheckout-payment-form').submit();
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
             //alert('Pleas');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does your code hit the `failure` part in Firefox? If yes, what is the `errMsg`?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: @Ahmad Basically after I populate the input fields am loading an external iframe which works well in Google Chrome. But in Firefox it throws an error of **empty values of orderID , orderRef**

Comment: @JustLearning Wont work in a JSFiddle cause am pulling the AJAX response from a PHP backend via AJAX

Comment: So basically, Firefox does not see orderID?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes...The same code works fine in Chrome